# Huffman encoding in matlab (binary values)

Tags: matlab, binary, double, huffman-code

I have a Huffman code in binary which is made by Matlab `huffmanenco` function. I store this code in a file and then retrieve it to create my main data again. I've done `dict` converting perfectly and also I do retrieve Huffman code as I wrote it in the file before, but when I use `huffmandeco` to get my data I get this error :

> Error using huffmandeco (line 67)
>    The encoded signal contains a code which is not present in the dictionary.
>   Error in extractNPSM_Huffman (line 75)
>     msg=huffmandeco(msg,cells)`

my code to retrieve data (I think there is a problem on my way to convert bit to double):

```
s = bp;
e = s + huffmanLen - 1;      
huff = [];
huff = bits(s:e);
for i = s:8:e
    k = bits(s:(s+8));
    c = 0;
    for j = 1:8          
        c = bitset(c,9-j,k(j));           
    end
    msg = [msg double(c)];
end

msg = huffmandeco(msg, cells)
```

Comment: I have to admit, I'm lost as to what you're doing here. I assume `bits` contains your encoded data and `cells` is your `dict`? Then it looks like you're flipping the bits of each byte of that substring. Why is that? Please post a [mcve] that creates a `dict`, encodes the input, and produces your error when you use the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no need to convert bits to number.`huffmandeco` needs to bit-stream as input param :

```
msg=huffmandeco(huff,cells);
```